# Returning aset of agents in a network component in Netlogo

Tags: netlogo

The following won't work because nw:weak-component-clusters reports a list of agentsets, not an agentset:

```
extensions [nw]
ask turtles[
ifelse any? nw:weak-component-clusters with [points > living] []
]
```

How do you make this work please? I'm trying to get a list of agents that can be reached by a network path from the current turtle, and find out whether they have turtles-own values for 'point' greater than the global value 'living'.

Comment: You want to know if at least one of the turtles in the cluster has `points > living`, or if they all do, or what?

Comment: Whether they all do - specifically whether all turtles that can be reached by a path from the current turtle have points > living

Answer (score 0):

`nw:weak-component-clusters` gets *all* the weak component clusters, not just the current turtles. Furthermore, these are *weak* component clusters, which basically treats all links as undirected, so will still report turtles that are connected by directed paths going the wrong way. Instead, you can use `nw:turtles-in-radius` with just a large radius to get all turtles reachable from the current turtle:

```
any? (nw:turtles-in-radius count links) with [ points > living ]
```

If, for some reason, you do want to use `nw:weak-component-clusters`, you can do

```
let component first filter [ member? self ? ] nw:weak-component-clusters
ifelse any? component with [points > living] []
```

Note that this is equivalent to my first solution for undirected networks.

Comment: I'm trying to use nw:weak-component-clusters to identify groups of turtles.  If A and B are linked then they're in a group, same with C and D. Then if A and C link, ABC and D are now all in the same group. Using components for this avoids having to deal with a group_ID that is easy to muddle when you don't know in advance how many groups there could be.

Comment: In the problem that you described above, you really want the group of the current turtle, which `(nw:turtles-in-radius count links)`.